# Why I am constantly seeing a number for "questions to review"?

Tags: discussion

I keep seeing a number in orange up by Review on the main site. If I click on it, there may be questions to review (for close votes, low-quality answers, etc.). But once I've gone through them, the number still remains. Even when I've acted on something (voted to close), the number doesn't change. And if I then click on the number again, all the items come up zero.

What's going on? How do I make that number go away if there isn't actual work which needs doing?

Comment: Pretty sure this was asked by people in chat a while ago. I don't recall the exact answer but it was basically a combination of "delay" and the number sometimes stays there until its been resolved (multiple people reviewed and decided what to do). Pretty sure that was the answer. I've not been seeing them as frequently these days though.